# SELECT CASE WHEN & INNER JOIN WHERE NULL or NOT NULL

Tags: sql-server, join

I have following `SELECT CASE WHEN` query:

```
SELECT CASE (WHEN TableA.UserId IS NULL) THEN 'CustomString'
ELSE User.Name 
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN User ON A.UserId = User.Id
```

Problem is that it returns only records where I have `UserId` different than NULL in `TableA`. But I should also include those records where UserId `IS NULL` and in that case return "CustomString". What should I add into query to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure UserId is `NULL`, and now empty string?  Try to add condition `WHEN TableA.UserId = '' THEN 'CustomString'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **LEFT JOIN**. More info on https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

```
SELECT 
        CASE 
             WHEN TableA.UserId IS NULL THEN 'CustomString'
             ELSE User.Name 
       END AS UserName
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN User ON A.UserId = User.Id
```

Also you could replace the CASE WHEN by a ISNULL function like this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(TableA.UserId, 'CustomString') AS UserName
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN User ON A.UserId = User.Id
```

Comment: Thanks, LEFT JOIN did the job. I don't know how it didn't come to my mind, I put the focus on INNER JOIN :/

Answer (score 0):

You should apply `left join`.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN A.UserId IS NULL THEN 'CustomString'
ELSE User.Name END as CaseUserId
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN User ON A.UserId = User.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

"it returns only records where you have `UserId` different than `NULL` in `TableA`" because (i think) you don't have a null `UserId` in table `User`. So maybe you should be using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Of course, I became confused a little bit yesterday on work, and LEFT couldn't come to my mind. Solution is pretty simple but sometimes brain becomes blocked :D

Answer (score 0):

Use this query with `LEFT JOIN` and inline `IF` statement like this:

```
    SELECT IIF(A.UserId IS NULL, 'CustomString', U.Name)
      FROM TableA A
      LEFT JOIN User U ON A.UserId = U.Id
```

In SQL Server 2012+ you can use the `IIF` function.